# Is quiescing a VM during a backup necessary for a consistent snapshot of the filesystem?

Tags: virtual-machine, backup, esxi, snapshot

Do I need to 'quiesce' a running VM to get a consistent snapshot of the disk at a point in time?

I do **not** care if there are unwritten buffers or if a running application is consistent with the disk. I only care that the disk itself is a valid filesystem and that the entire disk is accurate/consistent as of a point in time.

My goal is to have a valid backup of a Postgres database. Any very recent half-finished writes or transations can be lost as long as I have a valid database when restoring and booting.

My environment:

Host: ESXi 6.0
Guest: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Yes; It in the situation you describe it is

Answer (score 2):

To be 100% sure that your snapshot is going to be fine, the "ideal" should be done with the machine offline. As we know, that situation is not always possible because depending of the machine could be a production machine that can't be stopped.

It depends of the software you are running. Try to do it when there is the least activity possible. You know the software you have running, the concurrent users, the network traffic, the activity, etc.

If is a "normal" system, I mean as "normal" a server which is not part of a cluster, no DC, no database with replication, etc... there shouldn't be a problem even doing the snapshot with the machine online.

Beware if you revert to a snapshot of systems which has replication like Active Directory servers... that usually create sync problems and your AD database can be in trouble.

**EDIT** When I answered, there were no data about what kind of server is and what software is running.

Comment: The only data I care about is a Postgres database. According to postgres docs, it just needs a consistent filesystem snapshot to recover. Any unfinished writes / transactions can be recovered (or discarded) leaving the database valid and startable.

Comment: I think you can do a snapshot without any problem. Of course is a good practice not only doing snapshots... is good to have database backups! I think you know the snapshots can't be keeped forever... they are temporary for short periods of time because the more you use the machine while a snapshot is created, more size will have the snapshot.

Comment: Also, my real reason for asking is that my backups are causing my VM to hang and supposedly turning off quiescing will likely fix that. I just want to ensure that I still have a 100% consistent filesystem and the quiescing is not needed for that.

Comment: These snapshots are then put in another backup system and the snapshot removed. It's just a step in the process.

Comment: If you happen to know of any docs from VMWare that support your claim, then you are the answer. Otherwise, I'll wait a short time to see if there is any more convincing evidence.

Comment: Don't use snapshots as backups!! Snapshots are for punctual moments. Maybe if you are going to do something "dangerous" in the server to have the security of a returning point. Maybe this can give you some ideas. Is an official document to keep in mind good practices using snapshots. [Vmware snapshot best practices](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1025279)

Comment: The backups contain full disk images, not just some VMWare snapshot files. The vmware snapshot is used to just get a consistent image as of a point in time. I still understand that disk images aren't ideal and we are configuring a new server with better backups (using barman to make backups that we'll archive), but my question wasn't about best practices.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty much the same as to the question "If I pull the power plug on my computer without gracefully shutting it down, will it be OK when I boot it up again?"  The vast majority of the time, the answer will be yes.  Quiescing is basically a way of simulating a graceful shutdown without actually shutting down.  So the question you need to answer is, do you want to risk that one in a million chance that a file will become corrupt?